# Which kind of representation can be '\r\x00\x00\x00' (if usually I have hexadecimal code:'\x0\x00\x00\x03')

Tags: java, hex, representation, klee

I'm using  a program (klee) that give me tests of c code.
I need to use the results in my program.

It is not readable information, but some of the solutions are hexadecimal data with the next format:
'\x0e\x00\x00\x00'
I have already asked about how to convert it into integer, and I found the solution.

I will have to introduce this kind of results in structs too, I will know the size but any about the fields or anything else about it.

I think I can solve this but now the problem is that sometimes you can obtain things like:
 '\n\x00\x00\x00'= 13
or 
 '\r\x00\x00\x00' = 10

And I didn't found which kind of representation they use to convert it in readable information..
Apparently I could solve this in python with:
      import struct
      selection = struct.unpack('

I don't have any idea of pyton, and I would like found a solution in java or c.
 Thanks very much

Comment: `\r` is the ASCII escape code for "carriage return" -- 0x0D.

Comment: Wow, I've heard of klee.  Let me dig up the thing I saw that had it mentioned

Comment: klee has a tool to use the cases, and you can use this tool to use the cases with your original code. The thing is that I'm making a program in java (eclipse + linux) and I would like to take the information that klee give me (I have already done) and use it, so I should know how convert this kind of data.

Answer (score 0):

The value `\n\r` is used by Windows systems to indicate a newline - the `\n` moves to the new line, and `\r` moves the write pointer to the start of the line.  I'm thinking that you might have had some character data containing a newline where each character was converted into a 32-bit integer value in big-endian format.

Hope this helps!